# Multi Line Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio, charts

I have been trying to make a multiline graph which pulls data from a database. 
In an effort to do this i have written the following code to populate the chart:

```
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection();
    con1.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Removed"].ToString();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT YEAR(Start_Date) AS Year, Month(Start_Date) As Month, Cost, Utility_Type FROM import_Utilities WHERE YEAR(Start_Date) = 2011  AND Utility_Type = 'Water'");
    cmd1.Connection = con1;
    con1.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    da1.Fill(dt1);
    Chart1.DataSource = dt1;

    Chart1.Series["Series2"].XValueMember = "Month";
    Chart1.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "Cost";
    Chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend("Default") { Docking = Docking.Right });


    Chart1.DataBind();
    con1.Close();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Removed"].ToString();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT YEAR(Start_Date) AS Year, Month(Start_Date) As Month, Cost, Utility_Type FROM import_Utilities WHERE YEAR(Start_Date) = 2012 AND Utility_Type = 'Water'");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    Chart1.DataSource = dt;
    Chart1.Series["2010"].XValueMember = "Month";
    Chart1.Series["2010"].YValueMembers = "Cost";

    Chart1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
```

This code works except it has two data sources so only the bottom sqlconnection is populated to the chart.
I am at lost of how to fix this, and i imagine their is a better way to go about doing this but i am at a loss.

UPDATE:

Using the example bellow i ended up using pivot sql to make a table (see picture). [image: Pivot Table]
Then i updated my code to be the following:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT YEAR(Start_Date), CASE MONTH(Start_Date) WHEN 1 THEN 'January' WHEN 2 THEN 'February' WHEN 3 THEN 'March' WHEN 4 THEN 'April' WHEN 5 THEN 'May' WHEN 6 THEN 'June' WHEN 7 THEN 'July' WHEN 8 THEN 'August' WHEN 9 THEN 'September'WHEN 10 THEN 'October' WHEN 11 THEN 'November' WHEN 12 THEN 'December' END as [Month], [Cost] FROM [HousingAccountingReports].[dbo].[import_Utilities] Where [Building] = 'Building B' AND [Utility_Type] = 'Electric') TableDate PIVOT (SUM([Cost]) FOR [Month] IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December] )) PivotTable");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    Chart3.DataSource = dt;
    Chart3.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Month";
    Chart3.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "2010";
    Chart3.Series["Series2"].XValueMember = "Month";
    Chart3.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "2011";
    Chart3.Series["Series3"].XValueMember = "Month";
    Chart3.Series["Series3"].YValueMembers = "2012";
    Chart3.DataBind();`
```

When i run the page it errors to can't find column Month. And if i add:
   dt.Columns.Add("Month");
        dt.Columns.Add("Year");`
It can't find 2010, How do i get my chart piloting correctly; is their an issue with my pivot sql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Separating Chart Series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638639/separating-chart-series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question yesterday. [Separating Chart Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638639/separating-chart-series/22639073#22639073)

You cant change a charts datasource without reseting the data as you are doing in the above code.

Like yesterdays question I'd recommended you create one datatable first then reference columns in the datatable to your particular series

**From yesterdays answer**

> So as a suggestion to cleaning up the code, I would do the below
>
> 1. Get the 2 datatables
> 2. Merge the datatables with "Month" as the primary key
> 3. add each column to the chart as a new series

**Or you could manually plot the series**

so drop

```
Chart1.DataSource = dt
Chart1.Series["2010"].XValueMember = "Month";
Chart1.Series["2010"].YValueMembers = "Cost";
```

and replace it with

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt1.Rows
     Chart1.Series("Series2").Points.AddXY(row.Item("Month"), row.Item("Cost"))
Next

For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
     Chart1.Series("2010").Points.AddXY(row.Item("Month"), row.Item("Cost"))
Next
```

**if you manage to get all your data into one `Datatable` and have a chart with two series created then you can do the below**

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Month", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("2010", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("2011", GetType(Integer))

    dt.Rows.Add("January", 15, 25)
    dt.Rows.Add("February", 18, 32)
    dt.Rows.Add("March", 12, 34)
    dt.Rows.Add("April", 12, 34)

    Chart1.DataSource = dt
    Chart1.Series(0).XValueMember = "Month"
    Chart1.Series(0).YValueMembers = "2010"

    Chart1.Series(1).XValueMember = "Month"
    Chart1.Series(1).YValueMembers = "2011"

    Chart1.DataBind()
```

[image]

**Based on your code this should work to my understanding:**

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["removed"].ToString();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT YEAR(Start_Date) AS Year, Month(Start_Date) As Month, Cost, Utility_Type, Building FROM import_Utilities WHERE YEAR(Start_Date) = 2012 AND YEAR(Start_Date) = 2011 AND Utility_Type = 'Water'");

        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

    Chart1.DataSource = dt;
    Chart1.Series(0).XValueMember = "Month";
    Chart1.Series(0).YValueMembers = "2010";

    Chart1.Series(1).XValueMember = "Month";
    Chart1.Series(1).YValueMembers = "2011"

    Chart1.DataBind()
```

Data Table dt should have all data in it {because i am graving both years) (how can i bind it to a table so i can verify)

Right now its complaining series can't be used as a method however.

I am very new programmer, and only do this in my free time so forgive my simple mistakes.

Do i need to setup the data table like you did here:
        Chart1.DataSource = dt;
        Chart1.Series(0).XValueMember = "Month";
        Chart1.Series(0).YValueMembers = "2010";

```
    Chart1.Series(1).XValueMember = "Month";
    Chart1.Series(1).YValueMembers = "2011"

    Chart1.DataBind()
```

Or is it doing it based on the sql table?

Comment: I can get all the information on one table, by altering one of the sql commands to include both years. How would i differ between the years when i populate the series if they are all on one table in order to do step 3.

Comment: I don't understand for each statements yet but that is looking like what i need to do, it isn't a clean drop and replace as it isn't working if just do that. Do i need an assembly reference?

Comment: see edit I added an example...the for each statements would loop through each row of your datatable and add a point to the series using the data in that row, you would need to `chart1.series(0).points.clear` each series before plotting to make sure you erase all previous data

Comment: ok I see from your edit of my answer [which I will roll back eventually] try this first just do `Chart1.Series(1).XValueMember = "Month"; Chart1.Series(1).YValueMembers = "Cost";Chart1.DataBind()` and it will plot all cost values in one line. Next step you need to either pivot your sql table or merge two datatables so that your two different series are in two differency columns for each of the years. `MSchart` cant pick out the difference between the two lines unless you are very specific as to what you want to plot

Comment: Having never done a pivot sql and not truly understanding tables or for reach lops. Which one would you find would be easier to learn?

Comment: I would try and do clearing the points on the chart and then looping through the rows of the datatable first. Its a pretty fundamental piece of `.net` coding.

Comment: I ended up using pivot sql for the data, but it still isn't working. Please see update.

Comment: you needed to pivot so that the years are the columns not the rows. `Chart3.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "2010";` refers to columns not rows